# create a dict with first name as key, full name associated with the key as value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list:

```
name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
```

I want to write a function to return a dictionary which has first name as key, all full names associated with the first name as value:

```
 {'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel', 'Shelba Crowley', 'Shelba Fernald', 
 'Shelba Odle', 'Shelba Fry'], 'David': ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 
 'Brenton': ['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber'], 'Maren': ['Maren Fry'], 
 'Nicol': ['Nicol Barthel']}
```

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: use a collection.defaultdict(list) and go once through your list

Comment: `all_name = {n: [n2 if n2.startswith(n) for n2 in name_list] for n in [n3.split() for n3 in name_list]}` I don't believe I have the very first list comprehension correct, with the if statment.

Comment: @PrestonHager not quite - see the "bad" solution in my answer. List comp is not good for this kindof operation beause you traverse the whole list multiple times - a (correctly) used `defaultdict(list)` only traverses the list _once_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Smart way (1 pass through your list):**

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]

rv = defaultdict(list)
for elem in name_list:
    rv[elem.split()[0]].append(elem) 

print(dict(rv))
```

Output:

```
{'David':  ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 
 'Brenton':['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber'], 
 'Nicol':  ['Nicol Barthel'], 
 'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel','Shelba Crowley','Shelba Fernald','Shelba Odle','Shelba Fry'], 
 'Maren':  ['Maren Fry']}
```

---

**Slow way (might look nice, but is inefficient):**

```
d = {key:[n for n in name_list if n.startswith(key)] 
          for key in set( p.split()[0] for p in name_list)}
```

This is computationally far  worse then the `defaultdict` version because it traverses the list multiple times:

- *once* to create `set( p.split()[0] for p in name_list)`
- and for every name we just gathered it traverses the full list again to create the dict-value `[n for n in name_list if n.startswith(key)]`

---

If you need to sort afterwards, simply use the `list.sort()` on your `dict`s values:

```
# sorting the data afterwards
for k in rv:
    rv[k].sort(key = lambda x:x.split()[1]) # to sort by last names
```

Output:

```
# only difference when sorted: see key `Shelba`
{'David':  ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 
 'Brenton':['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber'], 
 'Nicol':  ['Nicol Barthel'], 
 'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel','Shelba Crowley','Shelba Fernald','Shelba Fry','Shelba Odle'], 
 'Maren':  ['Maren Fry']}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Artner suggested in the comments, use `defaultdict`. How about this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]

name_dict = defaultdict(list)

for first_name in set([name.split()[0] for name in name_list]):
    name_dict[first_name] = [name for name in name_list if name.split()[0] == first_name]

print(name_dict)
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Maren': ['Maren Fry'], 'David': ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 'Nicol': ['Nicol Barthel'], 'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel', 'Shelba Crowley', 'Shelba Fernald', 'Shelba Odle', 'Shelba Fry'], 'Brenton': ['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber']})
```

Comment: you are voiding the advantage of defaultdict by iterating the list multiple times when creating your values and creating the set beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def build_dict(name_list)
result_dict = {}
for name in name_list:
    names = name.split(" ")
    if names[0] in result_dict:
        result_dict[names[0]].append(names[1])
    else:
        result_dict[names[0]] = [names[1]]

return result_dict
```

The idea is to iterate of the name list, split each name into first name and last name, see if the first name is in the dictionary. if it is, look it up and append the last name to the list of last names. if it is not, assign it a list whose only member is the last name

Answer (score 0):

```
def name_lists(name_list):
    d = {}
    
    for name in name_list:
                
        first_name = name.split()[0]
        if first_name in d:
            
            d[first_name].append(name)
            d[first_name].sort()
            
        else:
            d[first_name]=[name]

    return d
```

Comment: Answer is technically correct, but quite inefficient, because you sort after each list insertion. It is also not specified that the output order should be sorted. Instead, it seems to be just following the input order.

You can also make the code much simpler and elegant  using the `setdefault` dictionary method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name_counts(name_list):
    result_dict = {}
    for name in name_list:
        names = name.split(" ")
        if names[0] in result_dict:
            result_dict[names[0]] += 1
        else:
            result_dict[names[0]] = 1
    return result_dict
```

Comment: Please always add an explanation when answering with code, it can help others in understanding what have been done.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name_lists(n_list):
    result_dict = {}
    n_list.sort()
    for name in n_list:
        names = name.split(" ")
        if names[0] in result_dict:
            result_dict[names[0]].append(name)
        else:
            result_dict[names[0]] = [name]
    return result_dict
```

Comment: Please include some information on what part of the problem you have targeted, and how you have fixed it